# Splitting webpage into 2 columns within a same area

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am extremely new to bootstrap.

Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TER</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Report Dated: 2/1/16</h1>
  <p>This part is inside a .container class.</p> 
  <img src="pics/images.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236">
  <p>The .container class provides a responsive fixed width container.</p>           
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to place text beside the picture. Something like this

```
Picture             Text
```

I would also like to increase the nav bar height to include my logo.

How do i go about doing this.

Sorry as i do not know what to google for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display picture and text sideby side.Then you can follow the bootstrap grid structure
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Example for your above question:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
  <img src="pics/images.jpg" class="img-circle " alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6"><p>The .container class provides a responsive fixed width container.</p> </div> </div>         
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

using css

take this

```
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQMQ6edupFreoXZgXczTGBGeR4EEVKx1x7KnEzbkzC6XXMzeDhZTA" class="img-circle" alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236">
  <p >The .container class provides a responsive fixed width container.</p>
```

and place it into a div container with `id='flex'` as follows

```
 <div id='flex'>
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQMQ6edupFreoXZgXczTGBGeR4EEVKx1x7KnEzbkzC6XXMzeDhZTA" class="img-circle" alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236">
  <span >The .container class provides a responsive fixed width container.</span>         
  </div>
```

the style using css like

```
#flex{
  display:flex;
}
```

snippet

```css
#flex{
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TER</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Report Dated: 2/1/16</h1>
  <p>This part is inside a .container class.</p> 
  <div id='flex'>
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQMQ6edupFreoXZgXczTGBGeR4EEVKx1x7KnEzbkzC6XXMzeDhZTA" class="img-circle" alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236">
  <p >The .container class provides a responsive fixed width container.</p>         
  </div>
</div>

</bo id=''dy>
</html>
```